# what is main/major difference between interface and abstract class in oop

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

I face this question in many interviews but here i exactly want to know the big difference between interface and abstract class in object oriented programming.

Anyone there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

Answer (score 0):

Interface:
1.Interface is not class
2.Interface use for – Data Abstraction, Future implementation.
3. Interface contains only the abstract members.
4.Interface contains the declaration, the class which will implement it will have to define/add the logic on it.

Abstract Class
1.Abstract class is a class
2.Abstract class is use for a base class.
3. Abstract class contains both Abstract + normal members
4.The abstract members have only the declaration (like Interface),but the normal members are getting define.

Answer (score 0):

One major difference of interface and abstract class is:

**if interface contains 9 methods and we implements that interface then we need to override   all 9 methods in our class.**

**if we take one abstract class and we extends that abstract class no need to override all 9 methods override only that method that wee need.**

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in interface we can only define the methods and variable and give body/values where it is implemented by overriding.
Where abstract class has the property of a normal class and an interface. We can just make the variables and methods abstract like interface and we can also add variables and methods with body/value in the same class.